# 50 Hz noise from mains plug even though it isn't connected to a power source

Tags: noise, frequency, mains, measurement, wire

I am developing a front-end for a smart meter and I'm trying to measure the mains by using a power lead with the other end spliced to connect it to the front-end. I firstly powered the setup with a function generator and I noticed 15V 50 Hz noise just at the lead end, coming into the front end. I disconnected the power supply and simply measured the active(A) and neutral(N) pins...and the noise still exists(see picture below). This also happens when I connect the oscilloscope probes to A-E(earth) & N-E. I tested with plug boards & extension leads and they all have it.
[image]
I have read up that this is the main hum noise but it happens even when it isn't connected to the mains. I tried shielding the wires with aluminium foil but it barely reduced(thinking it might be RF interference).

My question is how do I reduce noise of this magnitude. Is it a matter of using differential pins to get rid of the common noise? Do I need to use a properly shielded lead?

Thanks!

Comment: AC electric fields extend many metres.

Comment: Reduce the impedence at power frequencies